# MVCSiteMapProvider Breadcrumbs not back linking correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

MVC Sitemap Provider version 4.6.18.0 (assembly version) 
Using MVC4

I have setup the site map with some static root nodes with a dynamic node for displaying individual product items. For brevity lets say there are two product types

1) Bridal
2) Jewelry

each product type  has a type of Band associated with it. 
PROBLEM:
I have Bridal listed first in the Mvc.sitemap which seems to take precedence on breadcrumb display so the back links relative to the bread crumbs are incorrect.

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Bridal" controller="Products" action="Bridal">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Bands" controller="Products"  action="BridalRings">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="BridalRings" key="Bands" dynamicNodeProvider="Betteridge.Web.Services.ProductNodeProvider, Betteridge.Web" />
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Engagement" controller="Products"  action="BridalEngagement">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="BridalEngagement" key="Engagement" dynamicNodeProvider="Betteridge.Web.Services.ProductNodeProvider, Betteridge.Web" />
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Jewelry" controller="Products" action="Jewelry">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Bands" controller="Products"  action="JewelryBands">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="JewelryBands" key="Bands" dynamicNodeProvider="Betteridge.Web.Services.ProductNodeProvider, Betteridge.Web" />
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

....

[image: Jewelry Item displayed correctly with correct back links in breadcrumbs]
If I click on the text to view more detail on the item the crumbs change from Jewelry to Bridal.

[image: Changes from Jewelry To Bridal in crumb trail]

Why?

Here is my Dynamic node provider code.

```
public class ProductNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{     
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        string parent = "";
        if(node.Attributes.ContainsKey("parentNode")) 
        {
            parent = node.Attributes["parentNode"].ToString(); 
        } 
        List<ProductModel> products = DataServices.GetActiveProductBySubType(parent,node.Key);


        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>(); 
        foreach (ProductModel p in products)
        {
            DynamicNode dnode = new DynamicNode();
            dnode.Title = p.ProductName;
            dnode.Action = "Details";
            dnode.Controller = "Products";
            dnode.RouteValues.Add("id", p.ProductId);

            returnValue.Add(dnode);
        } 
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I know this has to be something simple I am overlooking. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

Multiple nodes with the same route values are *not supported* by `MvcSiteMapProvider`.

You need to add at least one additional parameter for it to tell the difference between a product that is listed under `Bridal` and a product listed under `Jewelry`.

The cleanest way would be to simply add this information to the route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Category",
    url: "{controller}/{category}/{action}/{id}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And you then just need to add the `category` parameter to your dynamic nodes. The simplest way is just to add it to the XML and it will automatically be included as a route value in every dynamic node created by the provider.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Bridal" controller="Products" action="Bridal">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Bands" controller="Products"  action="BridalRings">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="BridalRings" key="Bands" category="BridalRings" dynamicNodeProvider="Betteridge.Web.Services.ProductNodeProvider, Betteridge.Web" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Engagement" controller="Products"  action="BridalEngagement">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="BridalEngagement" key="Engagement" category="BridalEngagement" dynamicNodeProvider="Betteridge.Web.Services.ProductNodeProvider, Betteridge.Web" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Jewelry" controller="Products" action="Jewelry">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Bands" controller="Products"  action="JewelryBands">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="JewelryBands" key="Bands" category="JewelryBands" dynamicNodeProvider="Betteridge.Web.Services.ProductNodeProvider, Betteridge.Web" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

### Fixing SEO

It's true that putting the same content on 2 different URLs is a bad thing - that is, until you add a [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2) to indicate which one is the "primary" source of the content. This is how you can indicate to search engines that this is an intentional copy of the content.

`MvcSiteMapProvider` supports canonical tag generation simply by specifying a `canonicalKey`. You just need to ensure there is a unique key given to the "master" node and then use that same key for all of the copies.

To enable the canonical key generation, you just need to add the `CanonicalTag` HTML helper to your `_Layout.cshtml` page (inside the `<head>` element).

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().CanonicalTag()
```

In terms of your site design, it would be best if you had some way to indicate which category is the "primary" one in your database, and do the appropriate joins to ensure the key and canonical key are set appropriately.

I created a [demo project](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_MultiCategory) that just sets the canonical key as the corresponding product under the `BridalRings` category so you can see how it's done. Note that if you go to a product listing under another category and view source, you will see a canonical tag with a reference to the original content's URL.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:64658/Products/BridalRings/Details/1" />
```

Reference: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This works great in the demo and the only way I was able to make it work in mine is if I clicked the link from the generated link within the _Layout.cshtml page @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap().  I am using boostrap for the menu system. The user navigates to the desired products page and selects a product to view more details. even if I change the url in the generated page to  <a href="@Url.Content("~/Products/BridalRings/Details/"+@item[0].ProductId)"> to match the route which works then I do not get any crumbs. if and only if I use the sitemap link will it work.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by changing the following. 1) in my product page I added the distinct route <a href="@Url.Content("~/Products/BridalRings/Details/"+@item[0].ProductId)">  #2) in my sitemap I was using the code as the key for the product sub type. I added an additional attribute called code which I now use for the sub product type and that allows me to define distinct keys for each dynamic node. Learning curve. I appreciate your help. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

there were two issues. 
1) creating distinct routes to clearly identify product types which was defined in the sample application provided by @nightOwl888. 
2) within the sitemap definition there is an attribute "key" which must be unique so I have learned. I was using the key to define sub product types which when you have duplicate sub product types this will have conflicts and the first definition wins.

how I Solved this
1) I created an additional attribute called code. This code can be duplicated throughout the sitemap. This allowed me to pass duplicate sub types for parent categories.

2) now I have working breadcrumbs throughout.